# Spring Security - JEE tag with user-service-ref attribute loses mapped roles

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I'm pretty new to spring, let along spring security, and I've been looking at the Schema files and noticed a `<jee>` tag that appears under the `<http>` tag which acts like some sort of preauth filter magic. Using the `mappable-roles` attribute, I can get the role that I want but, when I specify a different `user-service-ref` attribute, specifying a `UserDetailsService` object, I lose the role.

My guess is because when I specify the `UserDetailsService` object, Spring assumes I don't need the role anymore... but I do!

Any ideas on this? Can I capture those details somehow? If not with this simple `<jee>` tag, what does the `jee` tag expand to for `custom-filter`s and pre-auth, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<jee>` tag creates (among others) a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` bean which delegates to a configured strategy for loading user details.

The default implementation of this strategy is `PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService` which will simply copy the roles it finds in the authentication token.

By overriding this default strategy with your custom `UserDetailsService` using the `user-service-ref` attribute you take the responsibility for assigning roles to the user. If you want to keep the default behavior regarding user roles, you can simply copy the [related line](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService.java#L44) from the above mentioned class, as the Java EE roles are still mapped, and are accessible in the auth token to your own code as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. You don't realize how many hours of research you've saved me. Thank you so much!